# Redux dispatch throws unexpected token error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**EDIT** tl;dr: Below is what happens when you forget to put a `type` property in your action. I'll leave the question up in case a Googler happens upon the same.

I'm getting an `Unexpected token` error when I apply `dispatch` in my `mapsDispatchToProps` function.

As a fairly minimial example, here is the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import './App.css';

const ToggleButton = ({ toggleButtonClick }) => (
  <div>
    <Button onClick={toggleButtonClick}>Toggle</Button>
  </div>
);

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { val: state.val };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { toggleButtonClick: () => dispatch({ 'TOGGLE_BUTTON_CLICK' }) }; //<--------ERROR OCCURS ON THE dispatch RIGHT PARENTHESIS
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ToggleButton);
```

full error:

```
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (18:69)

  16 | 
  17 | function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
> 18 |   return { toggleButtonClick: () => dispatch({ 'TOGGLE_BUTTON_CLICK' }) };
     |                                                                      ^
  19 | }
  20 | 
  21 | export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ToggleButton);
```

Comment: Post the full error.

Comment: Added full error message. I should add that deleting the dispatch function removes the error, although obviously nothing is dispatched..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { toggleButtonClick: () => dispatch({ type: 'TOGGLE_BUTTON_CLICK' })}
}
```

Note the `type:` in `dispatch()`.

Comment: OMG, I'm so stupid, I've been staring at that for an hour without seeing it. Thanks for your time, sorry to waste it.

Comment: No worries, happens to all of us! :)